# Word printing issue

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

My friend has an issue when printing a word document which I'd like to find a solution to. The document is simply a list of names, with a location associated to each name, as shown in the image below:

[image]

These details are being used to make name badges, so each name and location are to be separated using a guillotine and then inserted into a plastic cover to create each badge. Although all names and locations appear to be aligned identically in the file itself, after printing, some of the names/locations are what i would describe as 'top-aligned' and others 'centre-aligned'. I'm afraid I can't post a picture as the details are sensitive, but I think I can explain in words adequately. Each name and location sits in a white rectangle, so there is of course some white space around each name/location, but as I mentioned, some name/locations appear 'top-aligned' within this white rectangle and others 'centre-aligned'. This is not ideal, as it would be preferable to have consistency of appearance.

I'm not an expert on Word, but it seems to me that the author of the document may have put a line break between the left and right columns, as if I click after say 'Name 1' and press the right-arrow on my keyboard, the cursor doesn't go over to 'Name 10'; instead it moves down to the line below. Pressing it a second time moves it to the next line down again, upon which 'Location 1' is located.

I don't know what the cause of the problem is, but just wondering if anyone might be able to help. The next batch is to be printed tomorrow, but there will be others required after this, God permitting, so any help would be appreciated.

Here is a screenshot of the above file with paragraph markers displayed, in case this is of use:

[image]

Comment: Make sure that only one Style is being used.  Left align (Word Icon) all lines.  Make sure there is a hard Enter (new line) at the end of each line.

Comment: @John Only 1 style is used and it's all left-aligned. I'm not really sure how to check the hard-enter part. Enter may have been pressed at the end of each line, but not 100% sure on this.

Comment: Word Options, display paragraph markers.  That will show end of line.

Comment: @John thanks for this. I've just added a screenshot of the same file but with paragraph markers displayed in case this is useful. All the lines have one at the end but there is laso one after each name and location and between them in the left hand column. I guess I don't need to type '@John' but did so just in case,

Comment: What you could do is select an Avery Label type, set up the labels, enter relevant stuff in each label and print the labels. That will work.

Comment: @John Presumably this would require the printer to be loaded with labels rather than A4 paper though, right? We may not have any Avery labels to load the printer with at present but thanks for the info.

Comment: I just use standard paper and print "labels" on the paper.

Comment: Ah ok thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution proposed by John in his comments works fine. Just use Avery labels.